# Unable to connect from local machine to AWS RDS db instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

i am trying to connect AWS db instance through MySQL workbench, the current rdb instance engine is MYSQL 5.6.23 also i am under the free tier plan in AWS ap-southeast region (Singapore)

These are the follwing steps in MySQL workbench

[image]

The user name and password is already set by me when i click the Test connection i got error always like this in the below image

[image]

So i go to the RDS Security group of this instance amrita2016-rds (sg-970f10f2) in AWS and Add an inbound rule to that group for allowing connections from my machine see the image

[image]

after that i tried once again through MYSQL workbench getting same error also i am working under domain network . Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Check your Windows/ Linux Firewall.. Are they allowing connections

Comment: I just go to the Windows Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Action Center under the Security section Network Firewall is OFF also in my machine installed Sophos Anti Virus client . So this client firewall also in OFF mode but Windows update is ON

Comment: In your RDS server's configuration, is the "publicly accessible" setting enabled?

Comment: @Mark :yes in the security network of RDS its showing Publicly Accessible is YES i don't know why i cant connect to RDS instance